# I am computing cosine similarity of my product features but wanted to save the output so that i dont recompute it

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I am building cosine similairy index of my product features and since the feature space is huge i want to store the results after transforming my features so that i dont have to recompute it every time.Is there a way to do so?

```
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
    cv = CountVectorizer()
    count_matrix = cv.fit_transform(full_data["features"])
    cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(count_matrix)
```

can i store the cosine sim output and reuse it for a new entry while computing the similarity index?

Comment: Short answer: Yes you can. You can write it to a file. For a more complete answer, please show the structure of `cosine_sim`, what object type it is, and what you've tried so far

Comment: i get an output like this[1.         0.26726124 0.35355339 ... 0.30618622 0.20412415 0.25724788]
 [0.26726124 1.         0.50395263 ... 0.32732684 0.32732684 0.45834925]
 [0.35355339 0.50395263 1.         ... 0.28867513 0.67357531 0.40422604]
 ...
 [0.30618622 0.32732684 0.28867513 ... 1.         0.16666667 0.63012604]
 [0.20412415 0.32732684 0.67357531 ... 0.16666667 1.         0.28005602]
 [0.25724788 0.45834925 0.40422604 ... 0.63012604 0.28005602 1.        ]] a numpy array object

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. If you want to be able to open these similarities manually to inspect, then you can use np.savetxt(). If you want to store them to be able to use them in other scripts, then you can use np.save() and np.load()